# Make Edge/Face Giving Unexpected Behavior?

Tags: faces, edges

This is what I want

[image: Text]

This is what I get

[image: Text]

I am using F key aka Make Edge/Face

I have tried remaking it, I have tried fill it just says it has nothing to fill. I am a beginner with blender please help.

Comment: This looks like it is supposed to work right, but something about your process is ending up with some thing like duplicate vertices. I noticed some of the circular regions do not appear to be made of the same number for the says, which is a hint that some thing is non-uniform in the production method. Depending on what you intend to use this for, I would almost just instruct you on how to re-make it from scratch without problems.

Comment: I would rather just delete all the duplicate vertices one by one thanks tho I will give progress report

Comment: Try select all, merge by distance first.

Comment: I already deleted all the extra and it worked omg ty so much

Comment: God is good, your welcome! 